# Uninstall Plesk 9.5 CentOS

Tags: centos

I have Plesk 9.5 preinstalled on my (VPS) server, but don't like it.

How do I completely erase Plesk 9.5 on CentOS?

I would rather not ask my hosting company to uninstall it.

I couldn't find any documentation on this, besides some forums: "it is impossible to uninstall Plesk as it is bound very tightly with the OS."

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `yum` to uninstall (`erase`) all `sw-*`, `psa-*` and `plesk-*` packages.